# Accessing local https service from stripe webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am integrating a payment system using Stripe. In the process, I need to test the webhooks in my local dev. machine before I ship it to QA. I have tried the following,

1. Ultrahook: however when starting the ultrahook it said, authenticated <myaccount>, but did not give any "Forwarding activated..." message. When I tried to access the url from stripe or web, it did not work. Details below,

local url: https : //localhost/xxx/yyy/zzz
ultrahook command: ultrahook -k  localhost https : //localhost.com/xxx/yyy/zzz
hook url used in stripe: http : //localhost.arivanza.ultrahook.com/xxx/yyy/zzz

I have also tried, https : //localhost.com/, but the request does not come through from the hook when tested from stripe.

2. LocalTunnel: I could not find the way to launch the application after downloading it from the github.
3. PageKite: It by default opens up localhost:80, not sure how to open up the https://localhost.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ngrok: https://ngrok.com/ You download the app, launch it in a terminal or a console and it gives you a new url that you can set as a webhook endpoint. This will redirect to your localhost any event as expected.

Comment: Thanks, However, ngrok is not listening to TLS (https) in it's basic version.

Comment: Can't you ignore TLS/https in Test mode and use HTTP instead?

Comment: Well, I can, but the payment gateway tests usually expect the application to run on https. However, I took a short cut and using ngrok to listen on http 80 by running the app. in the same port. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For webhooks you can use HTTP or HTTPS, it's up to you so you can definitely test in Test mode over HTTP

Comment: Sure, Yep, Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have tried by self.
Please follow following steps

1. download **ngrok**  and extract in any folder
2. run ngrok.exe and type following command **ngrok http [port] -host-header="localhost:[port]"**
3. Y0u will get a url in ngrok console "Forwording" like https://7755afd8.ngrok.io
   this url is replacement of localhost:[port]
4. You can use no https://7755afd8.ngrok.io/index.html

Code example for stripe webhook using asp.net:

```
var postdata =new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var data = JObject.Parse(postdata);
var eventid = data["id"].ToString();
var eventdata = StripeHelper.GetStripeEvent(eventid);
if(eventdata!=null)
{
   switch(eventdata.Type)
    {
        case "charge.succeeded":
            //charged event
            break;
        case "customer.source.created":
            //card added
            break;
        case "customer.source.deleted":
            //card deleted
            break;
        case "customer.subscription.trial_will_end":
            //trial will end 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to receive webhooks on your local dev machine (let's say, on `localhost:1234/api/url`), you could use a local "mock" Stripe server, like [localstripe](https://github.com/adrienverge/localstripe). Once lauched, it will act like Stripe and send events if you configure it to.

1. Install and run localstripe:

   ```sh
   pip3 install --user localstripe
   localstripe
   ```
2. Configure your program to use `localhost:8420` (localstripe) instead of the real Stripe (`api.stripe.com`). For instance with a Python program:

   ```py
   import stripe
   stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_anythingyouwant'
   stripe.api_base = 'http://localhost:8420'`
   ```
3. Configure localstripe to send webhook events to your program:

   ```sh
   curl localhost:8420/_config/webhooks/mywebhook1 \
     -d url=http://localhost:1234/api/url -d secret=whsec_s3cr3t
   ```

Not all events are implemented in localstripe, and it could behave slightly differently from real Stripe. But it allows you to test your application in a local sandbox, without touching actual Stripe servers.

Answer (score 0):

Although the others answers work, I think they are a bit dated.

Stripe now has a CLI tool that allows you to create a connection between Stripe and your local host. Here are the steps

1. Create the webhook file that handles the Stripe webhook calls. Let's assume that path to this file is `http://localhost/webhook`.
2. Go to [stripe.com](https://stripe.com), go to the dashboard, then click on Developers, and Webhooks, then  add a new endpoint. Make sure the URL in that endpoint is the one from step 1 above (i.e., `http://localhost/webhook`)
3. Download and install the [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) locally. Then follow the instructions to `login`
4. In your Stripe CLI, run the following command:

   `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost/webhooks`.

   This will eventually listen to Stripe for any webhooks to your local server, and forward them to your sever locally (i.e, it creates a bridge between the two)
5. Test your work.

The problem with the above solution is it is not going to send back the responses of the webhook back to the Stripe server (because the `http://localhost/webhook` is private to your network).

If you insist on having responses back to Stripe, then you should either

1. Map your localhost to a public domain
2. Use a tunnel, such as `ngrok`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389694/1795917) describes how to use `ngrok`, but for me, I make the `ngrok` call this way:

   `ngrok http -host-header=localhost 80`

   The above call would give me something like `https://<some-random-numnber>.ngrok.io`

   So in stripe.com, I would have to write the endpoint as

   `https://<some-random-numnber>.ngrok.io/<path-to-webhook-response-page>/`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Although the others answers work, I think they are a bit dated.

Stripe now has a CLI tool that allows you to create a connection between Stripe and your local host. Here are the steps

1. Create the webhook file that handles the Stripe webhook calls. Let's
   assume that path to this file is http://localhost/webhook.
2. Go to stripe.com, go to the dashboard, then click on Developers, and
   Webhooks, then add a new endpoint. Make sure the URL in that
   endpoint is the one from step 1 above (i.e.,
   http://localhost/webhook)
3. Download and install the Stripe CLI locally. Then follow the
   instructions to login
4. In your Stripe CLI, run the following command:

   ```
   stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost/webhooks.

   This will eventually listen to Stripe for any webhooks to your local
   server, and forward them to your sever locally (i.e, it creates a
   bridge between the two)
   ```
5. register url in VerifyCsrfToken[Middleware]:
   class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
   {
   protected $except = [
   'webhook'
   ];
   }
6. Test your work