# Testing Stripe webhook over HTTPS keep failing : Timed out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, webhooks, ngrok, stripe.net

**Short version**

I'm trying to create a very basic webhook which redirects to a ASP.NET MVC Controller method on localhost. However, my website uses full HTTPS, and it seems my tunneling client ([ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)) fails with HTTPS.
Creating a new ASP.NET MVC website and implementing my webhook works, but I keep failing with my HTTPS website.

**Long version**

Here is what I've done so far :

1/ Create an endpoint on my ASP.NET MVC5 website and run it on **localhost**. It runs on port 44368, as my full website uses HTTPS.

```
public class StripeWebhookController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

2/ Install [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started) and configure it as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389694)

3/ Go to my Stripe test dashboard and copy the URL to be called like that :
[image]
(I tried to check the other RadioButton, "latest", but doesn't work better. I also tried to replace `https` by `http`, not better neither)

When I send a test webhook with the Stripe dashboard, I can see the request in `http://localhost:4040/inspect/http` :
[image]

But the breakpoint I've placed on the first line of my `StripeWebhook/Index` method is never hit. And a popup appears in Stripe with the sended request with this error message : `Test webhook error: Timed out`.

**However, if I create a brand new ASP.NET MVC website with the default template, and follow the exact same steps, it works. This is because my project uses HTTPS, and ngrok fails to redirect over HTTPS method** (as far as i understood.)

How can I use ngrok (or any other free tunneling tool) to redirect to a controller method over HTTPS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say from the information available whether the issue is ngrok related or your code related or something in between.

With ngrok you do have to rewrite the host, see [ngrok with https on localhost returns 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648031/ngrok-with-https-on-localhost-returns-502#comment88759918_49648031)

We also have a free tunnelling tool called Conveyor which installs as a VS extension.  You can just install it from Tools -> Extensions and signup for an account via the UI.  It should 'just work' once you have the public URL (which will be https).  It's possible that the same issue will arise, but I'm happy to help you figure it out.  You might find [this video](https://conveyor.cloud/Help/Writing_webhooks_on_localhost_with_Visual_Studio_and_IIS_Express) helpful too.

**EDIT By OP** : Just to make it more clear, I had to install Conveyor, then clic on "Access over Internet" and sign up on their website. Then, you're given an adress like `https://projectName.conveyor.cloud`. I just had to create a new endpoint on Stripe with this domain name and add my `/StripeWebhook/Index` route and it works like a charm

Comment: Yeah, wonderful ! I just edited your answer to make it more clear for future users